# Set useragent on Client __init__ (Python suds)

Tags: python, soap, user-agent, suds

I would like to know how to set the useragent in all SOAP request with suds in Python, including WSDL get.
Indeed, on the following code :
Client('http://...')
The WSDL is get with the default Python useragent.

The WSDL is available on the server only for specific useragent.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether that's the easiest way to do it, but it is certainly possible to do using httplib2 (this trick also gives you keep-alive connections) :

```
from suds.transport import Transport
import httplib2, StringIO

class Httplib2Response:
    pass
class Httplib2Transport(Transport):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Transport.__init__(self)
        self.http = httplib2.Http()

    def send(self, request):
        url = request.url
        message = request.message
        headers = request.headers
        headers['User-Agent']='XYZ'
        response = Httplib2Response()
        response.headers, response.message = self.http.request(url,
                "PUT", body=message, headers=headers)

        return response

    def open(self, request):
        response = Httplib2Response()
        request.headers['User-Agent']='XYZ'

        response.headers, response.message = self.http.request(request.url, "GET",
            body=request.message, headers=request.headers)
        return StringIO.StringIO(response.message)
```

And then you need to pass the transport class to the suds.client:

```
http = Httplib2Transport()
client = Client(url,transport=http)
```

Comment: Great, this allowed me to "fix" the server-side `Keep-Alive and Close may not be set using this property.` issue when trying to query with basic suds client.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `u2opener` method of `Transport` class to set your own `addheaders` attribute:

```
class HttpTransportCustomUserAgent(HttpTransport):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.user_agent = kwargs.get('user_agent', 'Python-urllib/%s' % urllib2.__version__)
        if 'user_agent' in kwargs:
            del(kwargs['user_agent'])
        HttpTransport.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def u2opener(self):
        """
        Create a urllib opener.
        @return: An opener.
        @rtype: I{OpenerDirector}
        """
        if self.urlopener is None:
            result = urllib2.build_opener(*self.u2handlers())
            result.addheaders = [('User-agent', self.user_agent)]
            return result
        else:
            return self.urlopener
```

Now you can use this new transporter class for suds.client:

```
http = HttpTransportCustomUserAgent(user_agent='My custom User Agent')
client = Client(url, transport=http)
```